# copying double[] values into an entire column in a datatable rapidly

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have a question about assigning array values (`double[]`) into a column in a DataTable in C#. I derived `double[]` from a column in my DataTable as shown below.

```
double[] ToBeChanged = mydatatable.AsEnumerable().Select(s => s.Field<double>("column")).ToArray<double>();
```

After updating some values in `ToBeChanged`, I want to get it back to the original column quickly. How can I implement it as simple or as quick as possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach would be using `.Zip` method

```
var pairs = mydatatable.AsEnumerble().Zip(toBeChanged, (row, value) => (row, value));

foreach (var (row, value) in pairs)
{
    row.SetField("column", value);
}
```

But I wouldn't advise to use it for production code, because correctness will fully depend on the assumption that rows and values ordered correctly.

Other possible approaches could be:

- Update values within `DataTable` .
- Pass `DataRow` instance to the method which will update values
- Use dictionary to associate updatable values with row identification value.

Comment: Thanks Fabio, it helps a lot!